# Flipboard style page turn animation

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-animation

I'm trying to write a fairly simple animation using Core Animation to simulate a book cover being opened. The book cover is an image, and I'm applying the animations to its layer object.

As well as animating a rotation around the y axis (The the anchorPoint property set of the left of the screen), I need to scale the right hand edge of the image up so it appears to "get closer" to the user and create the illusion of depth. Flipboard, for example, does this scaling really well.

I can't find any way of scaling an image like this, so only one edge is scaled and the image ends up nonrectangular.

All help appreciated with this one!

Answer (score 0):

CoreAnimation, by default, "flattens" its 3D hierarchy into a 2D world at z=0. This causes perspective and the like to not work properly. You need to host your layer in a [`CATransformLayer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATransformLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html), which will render its sublayers as a true 3D layer hierarchy.